# PHP echo not outputting inside of if conditional

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following conditional that is only partially working. It DOES correctly display the content or excerpt if they contain data, but the echo statements do not display. I can place the `echo '<h3>...` or `echo '<div>...` outside of the conditional (above or below) and they will display fine.

Using Firebug I have verified whether or not they are outputting.

**`echo` outputs nothing:**

```
<?php if (the_content()) : ?>
    <?php echo '<h3 style="font-weight: 300;">CONTENT</h3>'; ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
    <?php echo '<div class="fullwidth_bg" style="height: 20px;"></div>'; ?>
<?php elseif (the_excerpt()) : ?>
    <?php echo '<h3 style="font-weight: 300;">EXCERPT</h3>'; ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
    <?php echo '<div class="fullwidth_bg" style="height: 20px;"></div>'; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**`echo` outputs as expected:**

```
<?php echo '<h3 style="font-weight: 300;">CONTENT</h3>'; ?>
<?php if (the_content()) : ?>
    <?php the_content(); ?>
<?php elseif (the_excerpt()) : ?>
    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php echo '<div class="fullwidth_bg" style="height: 20px;"></div>'; ?>
```

Why are the `echo` statements not outputting inside of the first conditional above?

Comment: It looks like the_content() and the_excerpt() functions returns false...

Comment: Please show us some fiddle code, so that we solve your problem.@ Dark Anavger seems right that your two functions the_content() and the_excerpt() functions returns false.

Comment: @DarkAnavger But `if (the_content())` returns true and displays the page content if it contains data... I mean, how can <?php the_content(); ?>` get executed and pass right by the `<h3>` without it getting displayed with the `echo`?

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Ok, maybe you guys are right - maybe the_content() and/or the_excerpt are displaying on the `if` lines and not inside the `if` conditionals. I'll check my conditional logic and comment back.

Comment: You are both correct. I should be using something like `if (get_the_content() == "")...` - a big oversight. My logic was wrong but you both helped me identify it. Please enter an answer and I will mark it correct. :S

Comment: Great to hear that your problem is resolved :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following problems may occur in your code, please check :-

1. Two functions of yours the_content() and/or the_excerpt() returns false.
2. If not then  logic under these two function is not correctly working.

Please check both and tell us that your problem solved or not?